# vb.net visual studio 2015 setup project of localized application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, setup-project, localized

I wrote a vb.net (windows 7 - visual studio 2015) windows form localized application. It works fine in visual studio (realease mode), switching between  languages (it-IT and es-ES). But when I install on the end user pc (windows 7) it doesn't.
I created the setup project in vs2015. Did I miss something in the setup project?

Any ideas, tutorials, helps?

thanks in advance

Marco

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far. We cannot help you only from a simple description of the problem.

Comment: May be I found the problem (not the solution): the setup built with vs2015 doesn't copy resource dlls. At runtime, when the user switch between languages, the program doesn't find the right resource dll. If I copy manually the dlls, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I didn't add the group Localized resources in the Application Folder of setup project.

Thanks to Vincent for his help.

Marco

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! However I don't see how I helped you with anything.

Comment: You spent your time for my question, this is more than an answer! :-)